# How can I test NFC apps?

Tags: android

I am starting with NFC Android apps and I am a little bit confused. I am using Mono for Android (C#) and I have a reader ACR122U and different tags. I have used the emulator of Mono for Android to launch my basic android apps (without NFC) but how can I launch an android app with NFC?

For example how can I test if my app read or write a tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can use junit to test the logic of what you're reading and writing.
Things like robotium and roboletric will allow you to mock or control your applications interactions with Android components like intents.